# Join or concat multiple object observables and return unique objects

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have an object Person, that has a typical constructer class consisting off (ID, Name, Age, Gender, Status).

There are 5 observable calls:

```
const PersonalCall1: Observable<Person[]> = ... 
const PersonalCall2: Observable<Person[]> = ...
const PersonalCall3: Observable<Person[]> = ...
const PersonalCall4: Observable<Person[]> = ...
const PersonalCall5: Observable<Person[]> = ...
```

All the above observable's, do have endings and returns empty if nothing is found.

I have been trying to modify the following forkjoin, to join all observables together:

```
return forkJoin(PersonalCall1, PersonalCall2, PersonalCall3, PersonalCall4, PersonalCall5).pipe(
    map(([PersonalCall1, PersonalCall2, PersonalCall3, PersonalCall4, PersonalCall5])
        => PersonalCall1.concat(PersonalCall2, PersonalCall3, PersonalCall4, PersonalCall5))):
```

But I'm getting duplicates, and the results seem's a bit off.

Whereas with the method of concat,

```
return concat(PersonalCall1, PersonalCall2, PersonalCall3, PersonalCall4, PersonalCall5);
```

Results are correct, but duplicates are appearing of the same person.

I'm not able to find a suitable way to have all 5 observable calls combined somehow, and have unique Person's as a result

Comment: Results seem a bit off? Hmmmmm

Comment: The results don't have anything in common to what should actually be returned, i.e sent a request to find the name scot, I'm getting scot in the result, but there are results that are not related to scot, this only occurs when using the forkjoin as stated above...

Comment: `forkJoin` only returns the last emission from each source stream. `concat`/`merge` both emit every emission from each source stream.